# FFmpeg broken after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, ffmpeg

After upgrading Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04, ffmpeg no longer works. Running FFmpeg with any arguments (or none) prints this message:

```
$ ffmpeg
ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libcdio.so.17: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It seems to be looking for an outdated version of libcdio, which is odd since all my packages are up to date, including libcdio18. Looking at the installed files for libcdio18, there seems to be a version mismatch:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcdio.so.18
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcdio.so.18.0.0
```

Anyone have an idea how to fix this or at least work around it? I'm not sure if this is a bug or I somehow messed up my packages.

Also, I have tried using the FFmpeg snap and it is not suitable for my needs since it cannot write to /tmp. I've also tried removing and reinstalling multiple times using apt.

EDIT:
Output of `ldd $(which ffmpeg) | grep local`

```
libcdio_paranoia.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libcdio_paranoia.so.2 (0x00007f6a993e7000)
libcdio_cdda.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libcdio_cdda.so.2 (0x00007f6a991dd000)
```

EDIT 2: SOLVED thanks to N0rbert in the comments. This was my fault, I had been messing with CD audio related libraries some time ago in order to work around bugs in the repository versions of these to get the ripping program [whipper](https://github.com/whipper-team/whipper) to work. Everything worked fine in 18.04 but upgrading must have exposed the damage I did. After removing libcdio_paranoia.so.2, libcdio_cdda.so.2, and other junk in the /usr/local/lib/ folder, ffmpeg is working again.

Comment: Try reinstalling it `sudo apt install --reinstall ffmpeg`.

Comment: Like I said in the post, reinstalling does not work.

Comment: It works on a clean install of 20.04, so there must be some issue related to the upgrade. libcdio18 is version 2.0.0.2

Comment: Please show the output of `ldd $(which ffmpeg) | grep local`.

Comment: N0rbert, I've edited my post to include the output.

Comment: N0rbert, now I remember, I was messing with a bunch of CD audio related libraries to work around a bug present in cd paranoia at the time (for the ripping program whipper) and I must have messed something up that didnt get revealed til I upgraded to 20.04. After clearing out those old library files from usr/local/lib/, ffmpeg now works! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove locally compiled libraries by

```
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libcdio_paranoia.so.2
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libcdio_cdda.so.2
```

and then retry.